# Unable to handle mouse hover in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I want to get map/layer information (no profile or lat/long) on mouse hover on popup in a QGIS map. I don't know how to do it, please let me know?

Comment: Instead of hover can i use click to display same attribute data?
how can i do this without resorting to hardcore programming....html with css is just fine. thank you.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/76955)

Answer (score 3):

There is a howto that explains how to do this even without python. The feature is called *map tip*.

http://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/html-map-tips-in-qgis/

[image: maptip]

Comment: I want number of records on that lattitude and longitude without mouse click i wanna do it on mouse hover  event and also layers are dynamically added so this mouse hover event called automatically for all layer not for particular layer.